# Google YouTube Zend - Get Authenicated User

Tags: zend-framework, youtube

Ok, I'm succesfully getting authed with Google which is good.

$yt = new Zend_Gdata_YouTube($httpClient, $applicationId, $clientId, $developerKey);

Problem is - how do I get the authed users videos? The function below gets according to username but how do I get the user who just authenticated?

$videoFeed = $yt->getUserUploads('kornflake2007');

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
$userProfileEntry = $yt->getUserProfile('default');
$userName = $userProfileEntry->getUsername();

$videoFeed = $yt->getUserUploads($userName);
```

Default would be give the current user.

Looking at the code I am not sure this next thing will work. But its worth a try I guess.

```
$videoFeed = $yt->getUserUploads();
```

Without the name it should use the current user.